# Use dynamic Refs correctly in Vue 3 (Composition Api)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am struggling with the usage of dynamic refs in Vue Composition Api.
The [Vue guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/array-refs.html) says I could use it like this:

```
<div v-for="item in list" :ref="setItemRef"></div>
import { onBeforeUpdate, onUpdated } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    let itemRefs = []
    const setItemRef = el => {
      if (el) {
        itemRefs.push(el)
      }
    }
    onBeforeUpdate(() => {
      itemRefs = []
    })
    onUpdated(() => {
      console.log(itemRefs)
    })
    return {
      setItemRef
    }
  }
}
```

But with my code here (shortened):

```
<template>
    <section
      v-for="(item, i) of storyList"
      :ref="(el) => { if (el) { divs.push(el) } }"
    />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
[...]
export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    storyList: {
      type: Array as () => StoryList,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  setup() {
    const divs = ref([])
    
    return { divs }
  },
})
</script>
```

... I got only this in my Vue Dev Tools:

```
data:
divs:Array[0]

$refs:
function(el) { if (el) { _vm.divs.push(el) } }:Array[4]
0:<section id="story-0" class="story-item">
1:<section id="story-1" class="story-item">
2:<section id="story-2" class="story-item">
3:<section id="story-3" class="story-item">
```

That's not right, isn't it?
I should call the refs from `divs`, not from `$refs` (what is not working in vue 3), right?

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66737701/this-refs-empty-with-vue-3-options-api/67659614#67659614

Comment: pushing to divs is not a good idea, since you can possibly add more elements (component, DOM refreshes etc.). You should replace elements by index, so you always have right order and exact amount. An there is no need for `if` check. If you loop `storyList` and all goes right, you will always generate an element. Replace `ref` function with this and check if it works `:ref="el => divs[index] = el"`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have reactivity for array so for that use this:
`reactive([])`

Answer (score 0):

Use a reactive pattern to store `setItemRef`

See this [post](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/ejiro-asiuwhu_vuejs-vue-javascript-activity-6889282610598567936-mY9r?utm_source=linkedin_share&utm_medium=member_desktop_web) for more details